# How can i Go to the chosen tab from another page with Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

i have a 'index.html' and 'country.html' builded by bootstrap 3

'country.html' like this :

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="argentina"> ... </div> 
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="france"> ... </div>
```

---

and 'index.html' like this :

```
<h2>Let's Go to Argentina<h2/>

<h2>Let's Go to France<h2/>
```

---

How can i go to `#france` or `#argentina` tab from 'index.html' ?

`<a href ="country.html#france"></a>` doesn't work :/

Thanks for helps

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="argentina">
       ARGENTINA
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="france">
       FRANCE
    </div>

</div>

<a href="#argentina" data-toggle="tab">Argentina</a>
<a href="#france" data-toggle="tab">France</a>
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8902/